# Limiting site / list access with PnP.PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Is there any way that I can limit the account created with `Register-PnPAzureADApp` to a specific site, and ideally List?  The permissions that get created in the AzureAD app are broad - "AllSites.FullControl".

I'd like to limit the app permissions to a specific SharePoint online site, but it's not evident from the documentation if this is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can grant access to specific sites using the Sites.Selected permission:

[Controlling app access on a specific SharePoint site collections is now available in Microsoft Graph](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/)